# Cannot download correctly a gz file

Tags: okhttp

Trying to read "http://www.mtv.de/news_sitemap.xml.gz" but it seems data are not well decoded:

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://www.mtv.de/news_sitemap.xml.gz")
            .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        System.out.println(response.body().string());
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
```

Is it something wrong with the file, or something I should install/configure ?

Answer (score 0):

The file you're downloading is a compressed file. The command:

> System.out.println(response.body().string());

Can not extract the file and print out the content of the file inside. You should extract the file first, then print out the extracted file. Let's try below example:

```
  @Test
  public void testDownloadFile() throws IOException {

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("http://www.mtv.de/news_sitemap.xml.gz")
      .build();

    try {
      OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
      Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

      ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.body().bytes());
      GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
      InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzis);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

      String readed;
      while ((readed = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(readed);
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

  }
```

Comment: Ho, I believed OkHttp library handles this :/